# Neo4j Equivalent: Select Top 2000 of Node A, returning Node A and it's related nodes

Tags: c#, sql-server, neo4j, cypher

Up front, forgive me. I am usually a lurker and it has took everything in me to actually sign up for an account and ask this question... Apparently I can't figure out the right words search on to give me the answer needed.

**TL;DR - I need to query the database on a given node type with parameters, limit the node type result to 2000, while also including related nodes (but not limiting them to the 2000).**

I will start by telling how I got to this point, in hopes that maybe I have took the wrong path first...

I have written a Forex trading program that was sitting on top of a relational database (SQL Server). The client that is using my software kept asking for harder and harder relationships between data across multiple tables. I knew about graph databases and the way the node relationships were setup seemed to fall in line with the results I was needing in my program vs what SQL server was providing me.

I have started a pilot program on the side to see if I can move the original software from SQL server to Neo4j. In SQL server, I would have a table containing market data, and a second table that contained derived data from the market data with duplicated data between the two to allow for relationships to be setup (it wasn't the best approach, but I couldn't talk the customer off this duplicated data ledge).

I modeled this data in Neo4j as a "Bid" node and an "Ask" node. Both nodes contained market data. Those nodes are then fed into a "Market Info" node, that has derived data in it. So "[Bid] -> [Market Info] <- [Ask]".

The reason I did not create one "Market Info" node that contained the "Bid" and "Ask" data is because the "Bid" and "Ask" data is then also fed across multiple intervals of data. The base node is 5 minutes in length, but the program needs 5, 15, 30, 60 minutes intervals (and more). My idea was that the "Market Info" node would be the parent node, and I could vary the interval of the node based off how many sub nodes there were (5 minute Market Info nodes would contain 1 Bid and 1 Ask node, where as  60 minute Market Info node would contain 12 Bid nodes and 12 Ask Nodes).

In SQL Server, each interval type was given it's own table. So I had 5 minute tables, 15 minute tables, 30 minute tables, ect. It could have been a single table, but that's not what is being discussed here. I could easily query a table, selecting the top 2000 rows, ordered by date and continue my merry way.

In Neo4j, I can query the MarketInfo nodes and limit the result to 2000 but I also need to return the related Bid and Ask nodes. I started down the path of:

```
MATCH (a:MarketInfo {Pair: 'AUD/CAD'})-[r]-(b)
RETURN r, a, b 
ORDER BY a.EndTicksUTC desc
LIMIT 2000
```

Which does return the related nodes, but I can't control that the market info node is what should be limited, not the related node count.

Am I asking for too much? I am open to any suggestions, even if the answer is "You shouldn't be using a graph database for that...". This database is only going to get more complicated as I add different node types and build up relationships through the different levels of the program. It just sucks that I'm having this type of issue with the meat and potatoes part of the program. The lazy developer in me tells me to create a interval specific MarketInfo node, but I think that is running away from the problem and that I will have this issue further down the road as well...

Comment: Looks like there's already a good answer here, but in general a thing to learn when working with Cypher queries is that you do not need to perform everything at once in a single MATCH/WHERE/RETURN. You can make your query piecemeal, and limit only the parts of the query you want to be limited, and then continue with the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match all `MarketInfo` nodes first and then with each `MarketInfo` node match all of the immediately adjacent nodes.

```
MATCH (a:MarketInfo {Pair: 'AUD/CAD'})
WITH a
ORDER BY a.EndTicksUTC DESC 
LIMIT 2000
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b) 
RETURN a, r, b
```

Comment: It's going to take a while to wrap my head around this way of doing things, but that did work. I thank you for your time.